# Update scope variable doesnt change output

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

Appearently, I have not been clear in my previous explainations, so here we go:

```
function HomeController ($scope, Principal, LoginService, NewtagService, LoginfailService, $state, $http) {

    ...      
    $scope.contacts = [{name: 'Peter'}];
    ...
}

<div ng-controller="HomeController">{{contacts[0].name}}</div>
```

This prints 'Peter', whereas

```
function HomeController ($scope, Principal, LoginService, NewtagService, LoginfailService, $state, $http) {

    // $scope.contacts = [{name: 'Peter'}];

    function createServiceTag () {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/important'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.contacts = [
                {name:'Lois'}
            ];
            ImportantService.open(response.data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}

<div ng-controller="HomeController">{{contacts[0].name}}</div>
```

prints nothing

Comment: Why do you have a $(function() {} inside your 'then' function

Comment: remove this  $(function() {

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeImportantRequest () {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/important'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                      $scope.contacts = [
                    {name:'Luise'}
                ];


                ImportantModalService.open();

        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try it without the $(function (){})

```
  $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/important'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

             $scope.contacts = [
                    {name:'Luise'}
                ];
                ImportantModalService.open();

        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't change the result. I should maybe add that the value is being displayed in the modal that is being opened by ImportantModalService.The displayed name inside the modal remains Peter

Comment: then  comment **ImportantModalService.open()** this and try to run and see if it is working

Comment: I rather comment out the first assignment of contacts = [{name: 'Peter'}], the assignment should happen when entering the success callback.

Comment: Yet when I do so, nothing is being assigned. The name won't show at all in the modal where I access the variable.